# Как получить массив цветов из картинки?

Tags: изображения, ruby

есть такие картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как минимальным количества кода получить массив цветов в хекс формате из одной такой картинки ? ( на ruby)

```
[#0091C0, #70D6EC, #83B0E7]
```

или хеш чтобы соответствовал ,

```
 @colors = [ "Aqua Splach Heather", "Crystal Blue Heather", "Navy Blue"]
```

*к-во квадратиков на каждой картинке разное ( длина 56px)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взять `gem ruby-vips`.
Уменьшить в 56 раз (можно перепробовать разные kernel-ы).
Применить `Vips::Image#to_a`.
Взять первую строку и конвертировать каждый пиксель в hex.

Примерно так:

```
Vips::Image.
  new_from_file("my_image.png").
  resize(56, vscale: 56, kernel: :lanczos2).
  to_a[0].
  map{ |pixel| "#" + pixel.pack("c*").unpack("H*")[0] }
```

Comment: На нативный винде консоль зависла, от команды) либу поставил

Comment: @ЕгорRmd, ой, может там не 56, а 1/56.0.

Comment: где можно подробнее почитать, вместо scale может еще что можно прописать, и про фильтры lanczos2, какие еще бывают?

Comment: @ЕгорRmd здесь https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Image#resize-instance_method и здесь https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Kernel